# How to create .apk file from kivy on Windows

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to create a standalone `.apk` file from a kivy app. I am aware I can use the Kivy Launcher from the playstore to run the file, however I need a file that can run on any android phone without the Kivy Launcher. How do I do this on Windows 10 without using any Virtual Machines? (note: I can use Python 3.6/3.7).

Answer (score 1):

You can create .apk files with the Intelli IDE fom JetBrains. For my purpose it works fine 
[IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)